# Why do some scripts obfuscate element names? (e.g. "d\u0069\x76" for "div")

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, escaping

I have seen some people using **UTF-8 encoding** for creating elements like

```
document.createElement('d\u0069\x76');
```

Instead of

```
document.createElement('div');
```

Here is a [JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/eCEviVA/1/edit?js,console) which shows `'d\u0069\x76'` is encoded form of `div`. 
I am wondering why because the latter one always work everywhere.

Comment: Perhaps an attempt to inject HTML. e.g. some ad providers have scripts to prevent advertisers from abusing a customer's websites by detecting and disallowing certain forms of DOM manipulation. This could circumvent that.

Comment: Some cases are to prevent a class of xss attacks which center around injection of `</script>` into the text of a script.  If you have `<scr\u0069pt>` it's not going to end your inline script :D

Comment: BTW, this is not UTF-8 but, rather, a Unicode escape sequence followed by a hex escape sequence. UTF-8 is a way of encoding a sequence of Unicode characters, not a way of specifying them in JavaScript.

Comment: Obfuscation was the first thing which came in my mind as well. @Anthony Good point about preventing XSS attack

Comment: [More info on escape sequences in JavaScript](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive no benefit from using an escape sequence in JavaScript file over using a the corresponding Unicode code point if the value is in the Basic Multilingual Plane.

There are benefits in the HTML `<script>` tag, however. It allows you to specify HTML content without the browser confusing the tags in the script as HTML it should interpret, such as `</script>` (credit to Anthony Sottile for pointing this out the comments above).